# How to sort mongo db records in mule

Tags: mule, mongodb-query, mule-component

I am using Anypoint studio (v6.1.3) with Mule 3.8.0 CE runtime.

I want to get objects from one collection, using find objects from db option. There is an option to give sort reference . When i googled, one blog I found i have to give *org.bson.Documet* object in that filed. It did not worked for me.

Tried searching in google, but no tutorial or blogs found. In mule website, there is no proper explanation for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass something like `#[new org.bson.Document("filedName",-1)]` or `#[new com.mongodb.BasicDBObject("filedName",-1)]` for sorting. Here 'filedName' is the field name with which sorting will be done second parameter `1` for ascending order and `-1` for descending order

```
<mongo:find-documents config-ref="Mongo_DB__Configuration" collection="test" sortBy-ref="#[new org.bson.Document(&quot;_id&quot;,-1)]" doc:name="Mongo DB"/>
```

Hope this help.